# Insercion directa de un diccionario ne python a una tabla en SQL server

Tags: python, sql-server, diccionarios

Necesito realizar una inserción directa de un diccionario en python a una tabla en SQL server; ya que mi tiempo de procesamiento me esta limitando demasiado y estoy buscando reducir al máximo posible.

He intentado hacer la inserción pero no logro conseguirlo.

Adjunto una pequeña parte del diccionario en python.

```py
{
  u'FeatureResults': [
    {
      u'TolMin': 4.0,
      u'Unit': '',
      u'Feature': 'Macro Defect Objects',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120000,
      u'TolMax': 0.5,
      u'Value': 0.0,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 0.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': -3.0,
      u'Unit': 'mm',
      u'Feature': 'Width',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120001,
      u'TolMax': 7.0,
      u'Value': 5.831940174102783,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 5.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': -6.0,
      u'Unit': 'mm',
      u'Feature': 'Length',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120006,
      u'TolMax': 12.0,
      u'Value': 51.599998474121094,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 49.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': -7.0,
      u'Unit': 'mm2',
      u'Feature': 'Cross-Section Area',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120009,
      u'TolMax': 40.0,
      u'Value': 8.661370277404785,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 6.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': -0.5400000214576721,
      u'Unit': 'mm',
      u'Feature': 'Throat Thickness',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120011,
      u'TolMax': 6.5,
      u'Value': 2.609760046005249,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 0.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': 110.0,
      u'Unit': 'deg',
      u'Feature': 'Weld Toe Left',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120013,
      u'TolMax': 300.0,
      u'Value': 171.94500732421875,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 0.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': 90.0,
      u'Unit': 'deg',
      u'Feature': 'Weld Toe Right',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120014,
      u'TolMax': 300.0,
      u'Value': 174.7429962158203,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 0.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': 0.0,
      u'Unit': '',
      u'Feature': 'Zero Point Ratio',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120017,
      u'TolMax': 1.0,
      u'Value': 0.024989400058984756,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 0.0
    },
    {
      u'TolMin': -0.2199999988079071,
      u'Unit': 'mm',
      u'Feature': 'Depth Undercuts Left',
      u'Result': 'OK',
      u'FeatureId': 120019,
      u'TolMax': 0.0,
      u'Value': -0.0053483000956475735,
      u'TolActive': 1,
      u'TolRefVal': 0.0
    },
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar como estas intentando realizar la inserción en tu base de datos? Además del error que te impide insertar y la configuración de tu conexión desde Python a SQL.